# Why is rendering non - deterministic when using expo-gl and react-navigation/native-stack libraries together in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webgl

I'm developing an implementation of Conway's Game of Life using React Native through Expo CLI, which is my first attempt at an RN app.  The app's main screen includes a GLView component, onto which a view of the game board is rendered using the WebGL API provided by expo-gl.  This component works as expected when the main screen is the only screen.  However, when I put that screen into a stack navigator (using react-navigation/native-stack) it gets rendered in a non - deterministic way on Expo Go on Android.  Without any change to my source code the GLView component can change size between one reload to Expo Go and the next with no obvious pattern, as shown in the screenshots below.

[image: Option 1]
[image: Option 2]

Below are the two relevant modules.

**MainScreen.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import { GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import { ControlBarButton, ControlBarPlaceHolder } from './react-components/ControlBar.js';
import { onContextCreation } from './logic-components/GameBoardRenderer.js';
import { control, initialiseControls } from './logic-components/StateControler.js';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainScreenContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
    flexDirection: "column-reverse"
  },
  bottomControlBar: {
    flex: 0.1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 0, 160)"
  },
  gameBoardContainer: {
    flex: 0.8,
    backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
  },
  topControlBar: {
    flex: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
});

// These functions are handlers for touch input received by the GLView component that contains
// the game board.
function handleTouchRelease(window, evt) {
  control.flipCellStateOnTouch("touchReleased", window, 
                               {x: evt.nativeEvent.locationX, y: evt.nativeEvent.locationY});
}

function handleTouchMove(window, evt) {
  control.flipCellStateOnTouch("touchMoved", window, 
                               {x: evt.nativeEvent.locationX, y: evt.nativeEvent.locationY});
}

// This component is a container for eight buttons that appear at the bottom of the screen.
const ControlBar = ({buttonHeight, window}) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("creative");
  const onPlayPausePressed = () => {
    control.changeMode(false);
    if (mode === "simulation") {setMode("creative")}
    else {setMode("simulation")}
  };
  const onResetPressed = () => {
    control.changeMode(true);
  };
  return (
    <View style={[styles.bottomControlBar, {width: window.width}]}>
      <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                        imageSource={(mode === "creative") ? require("./assets/playButton.png") :
                                                             require("./assets/pauseButton.png")}
                        onPress={onPlayPausePressed}
                        disabled={false} />
      <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                        imageSource={(mode === "creative") ? require("./assets/resetButton.png") :
                                                             require("./assets/greyResetButton.png")}
                        onPress={onResetPressed}
                        disabled={(mode === "simulation") ? true : false} />
      <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                        imageSource={require("./assets/upButton.png")}
                        onPress={control.moveCameraUp}
                        disabled={false} />
      <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                        imageSource={require("./assets/downButton.png")}
                        onPress={control.moveCameraDown}
                        disabled={false} />
      <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                        imageSource={require("./assets/leftButton.png")}
                        onPress={control.moveCameraLeft}
                        disabled={false} />
      <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                        imageSource={require("./assets/rightButton.png")}
                        onPress={control.moveCameraRight}
                        disabled={false} />
      <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                        imageSource={require("./assets/plusButton.png")}
                        onPress={control.moveCameraForward}
                        disabled={false} />
      <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                        imageSource={require("./assets/minusButton.png")}
                        onPress={control.moveCameraBack}
                        disabled={false} />
    </View>
  );
};

// This component defines the layout of the application's main screen, which contains an
// interactive view of the game board and a number of controls.
const MainScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const window = useWindowDimensions();
  const buttonHeight = window.height * 0.1;
  initialiseControls();

  return (
    <View style={[styles.mainScreenContainer, {paddingTop: window.height * 0.04}]}>
      <ControlBar buttonHeight={buttonHeight} window={window} />
      <GLView style={[styles.gameBoardContainer, {width: window.width}]}
              onContextCreate={onContextCreation}
              onStartShouldSetResponder={(evt) => {return true}}
              onMoveShouldSetResponder={(evt) => {return true}}
              onResponderRelease={(evt) => handleTouchRelease(window, evt)}
              onResponderMove={(evt) => handleTouchMove(window, evt)}
               />
      <View style={[styles.topControlBar, {width: window.width}]}>
        <ControlBarPlaceHolder buttonHeight={buttonHeight} flex={7} colour={"rgb(0, 0, 0)"} />
        <ControlBarButton buttonHeight={buttonHeight}
                          imageSource={require("./assets/menuButton.png")}
                          onPress={() => {navigation.navigate("MainMenu")}}
                          disabled={false} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MainScreen;
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import MainScreen from './MainScreen.js';
import MainMenu from './MainMenu.js';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="MainMenu" component={MainMenu}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm using Expo CLI 4.12.1, react-navigation/native 6.0.6 and react-navigation/native-stack 6.2.5.  Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour and if there's a way to avoid it?  Thanks.